# Compare two column and fetch data from another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image: My Data]

I want to compare Column A and Column C. And want to fetch data from Column B. All are in same table.But when I searched with 'C' column data I found diferent date. I need that date.

Comment: What is your expected output, or what is the logic behind your update, etc.?

Comment: We can't read your mind, please explain what you want to happen in detail.

Comment: please provide any condition for the comparison


we couldn't get your logic by simple mentioning "compare"

Answer (score 0):

```
select  b from table where a=c;
```

in this case a and c columns having the same data  type. i.e character varying

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select date(b) from table name where a=c
```

As per you data it will return the null output

All columns in the table were value except column c

But you are indicated column c return date. Check it